# First day of week (beginning with Sunday)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I found that there is a function `last_day` for last day of month, and `date_part(dow, date)` for numeric day of week starting with Sunday, but I am trying to take a date, and get the first day of that week.

Meaning: if date='`2018-02-14`' then result should be '`2018-02-11`'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You simply want to subtract the `dow` value from the current date.

```
select dateadd(d, -datepart(dow, my_date), my_date)  
from (select date('2018-02-14') as my_date)

> 2018-02-11 00:00:00.0
```

For example, if `dow` is 3 for `2018-02-14` - a Wednesday - you can subtract 3 days to get back to "day 0".

---

There's also the [`date_trunc`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html) function which will truncate everything after a given datepart. This is a little clunky, and will only set you back to the previous *Monday*, not *Sunday*.

```
select date_trunc('week', my_date)
from (select date('2018-02-14') as my_date)
```

Comment: Thank Kirk- so you are confirming that no formula exists right?

Comment: I'm not aware of a `start_of_week` function. There is a `week` datepart, so you can use `datepart(wk, my_date)`, but I don't think that will be useful for you.

Comment: @user8834780 found another function for you which might help.

Comment: `dateadd(d, 1, date_trunc(week, dateadd(d -1, dt)))`

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if there is a more efficient solution but:

```
date_trunc('week',my_date + '1 day'::interval)::date - '1 day'::interval as week_start
```

Comment: this also worked for me! thank you!

Comment: This works but could you explain the logic here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get First day of week with week start day is any day in the week (Monday, Tuesday, ...). You can use this way:

**`day_of_week_index` mapping:**

```
{
    'monday': 1,
    'tuesday': 2,
    'wednesday': 3,
    'thursday': 4,
    'friday': 5,
    'saturday': 6,
    'sunday': 7
}
```

**Query Template:**

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN extract(ISODOW FROM datetime_column) < day_of_week_index THEN cast(date_trunc('week', datetime_column) AS date) - 8 + day_of_week_index
    ELSE cast(date_trunc('week', datetime_column) AS date) - 1 + day_of_week_index
END
FROM table_name;
```

**Example:**

Get First day of week with week start day is **Wednesday**

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN extract(ISODOW FROM TIMESTAMP '2021-12-03 03:00:00') < 3 THEN cast(date_trunc('week', TIMESTAMP '2021-12-03 03:00:00') AS date) - 8 + 3
    ELSE cast(date_trunc('week', TIMESTAMP '2021-12-03 03:00:00') AS date) - 1 + 3
END;
```

=> Result:

```
2021-12-01
```

**Note:** You can change the `day_of_week_index` following the above mapping to determine the week start day (Monday, Tuesday, ..., Sunday).